# Why portlet is renderRequest.setAttribute return the last variable?

Tags: java, jsp, liferay, liferay-6

I explain my problem:

I am using Liferay 6.1 and I am trying to understand the functioning of Documents and Media control Panel.

- In my portlet view I have a table which displays a list of documents one of these fields is the modification date. By default this date is the file modification date.
- In the java code I need to check this date field (optional), if it is empty I keep the old code(display the modification date of the document) if it is not empty then I want to display its value instead (the value of the optional date).
- I created a document type and I added a field in the document type called date(optional) to manually add the date.
- One of the things I did not understand, when trying to add a field ddm-date type the date field should have a default value, it can't be empty
  am I wrong?

My first problem, How to set ddm-date type to empty?

- In the creation of the field when I put None in the prefered value the CMS change it automatically to a default value and in the Form (when adding new file ) the select data of optional date doesn't contain an empty value as I see (by default it contains today's date).
- So I used text field as type.

**My main problem:**

I displayed the optional date but it overwrites all creation dates. in the display I only get the optional date and the last one. I explain when I add a file from Documents and Media control Panel with the optional date field for example with the value '2012/08/01', all values in the table are replaced by this value.

I sent my variable from java code using `renderRequest.setAttribute`
and I displayed it in my view with JSTL - Core  `<fmt: formatDate value = "$ {optionalDate}" pattern = "MMM yyyy" />` tag. also my portlet extends from MVCPortlet.

Why doView is render `renderRequest.setAttribute` return the last variable?

In my java code:

```
    for(DLFileEntry file : listFiles){
    try {
    Map<String, Fields> fieldsMap = file.getFieldsMap(file.getFileVersion().getFileVersionId());
         if(fieldsMap.values().size() <= 0)
            listContextFiles.remove(file);

    for (Fields fields : fieldsMap.values()) { 
    if(...){
      if(...){
      }
      else{ 
         if(fields.get("optionaldate") != null ) {
         DateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
         String _optionalDate = (String) fields.get("optionaldate").getValue();
         Date optionalDate = dateFormat1.parse(_optionalDate);
         file.setModifiedDate(optionalDate);
         renderRequest.setAttribute("optionalDate", optionalDate);
         System.out.println(file.getModifiedDate());
         listDate.add(dateFormat.format(file.getModifiedDate()));
         }
         else{
            renderRequest.setAttribute("optionalDate", file.getModifiedDate());                  
            if(!listDate.contains(dateFormat.format(file.getModifiedDate()))){
            listDate.add(dateFormat.format(file.getModifiedDate()));
            } 
         }
         //other conditions
     }
...
```

In my view.jsp:

```
<liferay-ui:search-container iteratorURL="<%=actionURL%>" delta="10"
        emptyResultsMessage="no-documents">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-results total="<%=list.size()%>"
            results="<%=ListUtil.subList(list,
                                        searchContainer.getStart(),
                                        searchContainer.getEnd())%>" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-row modelVar="file"
            className="DLFileEntry">

            <!--other code-->

            <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name='date'
                cssClass="txt-capitalize width-10">
                <fmt:formatDate value="${optionalDate}" pattern="MMM yyyy" />
            </liferay-ui:search-container-column-text>

            <!--other code-->

        </liferay-ui:search-container-row>

    </liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Is there a clean way to do all this?

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Hello, i can found a solution. my question still on [on hold] .

Comment: Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unwind all the loops, first in Java, then in the JSP, you're basically executing these commands (in this order), given 3 objects to be shown:

```
renderRequest.setAttribute("optionalDate", someDate);
renderRequest.setAttribute("optionalDate", someOtherDate);
renderRequest.setAttribute("optionalDate", yetSomeOtherDate);
```

followed by reading the value in the JSP:

```
renderRequest.getAttribute("optionalDate");
renderRequest.getAttribute("optionalDate");
renderRequest.getAttribute("optionalDate");
```

As `setAttribute` is not `pushToQueue` and `getAttribute` is not `nextFromQueue` (figuratively speaking), you'll only get `yetSomeOtherDate` for all iterations of your JSP loop, naturally.

You can either

- calculate the value in your JSP,
- store an object that does the calculation for you, based on the current object,
- store the attribute using the object's ID as part of its key, e.g. `"optionalDate-" + file.getId()` instead of just the generic `"optionalDate"`. Then use the same key construction in the JSP to read the proper value. (IMHO this is quite inelegant, but might be pragmatic for your usecase)